# Firefox and Chrome windows are smaller than all the rest

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, display-resolution

I installed 19.04 yesterday and noticed the Firefox window's set resolution was different from any other app in Ubuntu. Basically, everything looks smaller, text and bookmark icons, and when you put its window next to any other app's, you notice that the minimize, maximize and close buttons are also a lot smaller. It's as if it's opening in a different resolution. I downloaded Chrome to see if it had the same issue, and yup, it also does. I need to squint my eyes to be able to read!

Can you help me?

Comment: Press `Ctrl` + `0`. This resets the zoom factor (which can be changed with `Ctrl` + `+` and `Ctrl` + `-`).

Comment: No, that's not it. That resets that tab's resolution. What I'm talking about is the entire application. Even the bookmarks and menu text are small.

Comment: I'm not seeing any issue on Kubuntu 19.04. I've also watched a few videos on 19.04's release without coming across such an issue. What about other applications such as gedit, nautilus, and libreoffice?

Comment: Do you have a high DPI display, and are the affected packages snap packages? I do not know the status of snap on 19.04, but on 18.04 snaps do not respect your theme, and that includes the display scaling. Many snap applications are unusable on my Dell XPS 13 with HDPI display for this reason - typical symptoms are tiny minimize, maximize and close buttons and menus, and in some apps the mouse pointer too. Work around: search for PPA and install from there using `sudo apt install ...` rather than with snap.

Comment: @B.Tanner, if the poster is using the default Firefox, it probably *won't* be a snap.

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox, navigate to `about:config` in your URL bar.

Then, click the "I'll be careful warning" and enter `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` in the search bar.

Double click on the value, which is set to `-1.0` by default, and input a value greater than `1.0` and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Mess around with this value until you find one that looks subjectively good.